# Automorphism group of stack of torsors

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $S$ be a scheme and let us denote a fixed site over it by $S$, too. Let $G$ be a commutative group scheme over $S$. We define the stack $\operatorname{Tors}_G$ of $G$-torsors over $S$ as follows. For any $T/S$, $\operatorname{Tors}_G(T)$ consists of the groupoid of $G_T$-torsors over $T$. I would like to determine the automorphism group of $\operatorname{Tors}_G$.

Some observations:
since $G$ is commutative, $\operatorname{Tors}_G(T)$ is a $2$-group, i.e. a group object in the $2$-category of groupoids. Put simply, each object $\operatorname{Tors}_G(T)$ has automorphisms and there is a way of multiplying objects. Locally, therefore, I need to determine the automorphisms of a $2$-group. I am also curious what happens when $G$ is not commutative -- in that case, $\operatorname{Tors}_G(T)$ is merely a groupoid with the trivial $G$-torsor as a distinguished object.

Let us stick to $S$-points now to simplify notation.
The automorphism group of the trivial $G$-torsor $G_r$ is just $G$ itself. More generally, the automorphisms of a $G$-torsor, considered as a class in $H^1(S, G)$, are given by the form of $G$ corresponding to that same class in $H^1(S, G)$. I do not however want to assume that my automorphisms of $\operatorname{Tors}_S(S)$ fix the groupoid pointwise, so the automorphism group should be larger. I'm not sure how to proceed.